# How i can decode eval javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm in trouble now!
I have tried several ways to decode this script but it didn't work...

The code below -

```
eval(function(variable_0, variable_1, variable_2, variable_3, variable_4, variable_5) {
    variable_4 = function(variable_2) {
        return (variable_2 < variable_1 ? "" : variable_4(parseInt(variable_2 / variable_1))) + ((variable_2 = variable_2 % variable_1) > 35 ? String["fromCharCode"](variable_2 + 29) : variable_2.toString(36))
    };
    if (!"" ["replace"](/^/, String)) {
        while (variable_2--) {
            variable_5[variable_4(variable_2)] = variable_3[variable_2] || variable_4(variable_2)
        };
        variable_3 = [function(variable_4) {
            return variable_5[variable_4]
        }];
        variable_4 = function() {
            return "\w+"
        };
        variable_2 = 1;
    };
    while (variable_2--) {
        if (variable_3[variable_2]) {
            variable_0 = variable_0["replace"](new RegExp("\b" + variable_4(variable_2) + "\b", "g"), variable_3[variable_2])
        }
    };
    return variable_0;
}("3 1j(t){C(c e=t.1a,a=(e.11||[],e.11[0]),n=0;n<a.V.j;++n)\"1S\"==a.V[n].1V&&(N.2c=a.V[n].R)}3 1s(t){d=z.1i(\"d\"),d.F=\"/15/1b/1e?2k-29=\"+t+\"&1f-1g=1&K=1n-1p-d&1q=1j\",d.1v=\"S/Z\",z.12(\"14\")[0].M(d)}3 16(t){c e=t.1a,a=1K(e.1T$1U.$t,10),n=18.1W(18.1Y()*a);n++,1s(n)}3 1Z(){c t=z.1i(\"d\");t.1v=\"S/Z\",t.F=\"/15/1b/1e?1f-1g=0&K=1n-1p-d&1q=16\",z.12(\"14\")[0].M(t)}$(N).O(3(){$(\"#2b 1d\").2i({A:7,1A:1B,1C:!0,1E:1F,1G:!0,1H:!0,1I:{1J:{Q:1M,A:4},1N:{Q:1O,A:5},1Q:{Q:1R,A:6}}})}),$(3(){3 t(t){c e=$(\".9-q 1h\");\"v\"==t&&e.v().j?$(\".9-q .f\").1m().v().b(\"a\").1o(\"y\"):\"o\"==t&&e.o().j&&$(\".9-q .f\").1m().o().b(\"a\").1o(\"y\")}$(\".9-q\").X(3(){c t=\"2d\",e=\"1x\",a=$(\"E, 2l\"),n=1y,i=1z;$(8).p(\"9-13\").1D('<B H=\"9-L\" 17=\"u:'+t+'19;\"></B>');c s=$(\"1h:1L a\",8),l=s.1c(\"R\"),r=$(8).D(\".9-L\");s.p(\"f\"),r.1P('<B H=\"9-k\" 17=\"x:'+e+'19;\"></B>'),r.b(\".9-k\").p(\"G\").E('<m H=\"I\" F=\"'+l+'\" K=\"1k...\"/>'),r.b(\"m.I\").1l(\"J\",0).O(3(){r.h({u:$(8).u()},i).b(\".9-k\").h({x:$(8).x()},i,3(){$(8).T(\"G\").b(\"m\").h({J:1},n)})}),$(\"a\",8).X(3(t){t+=1,$(8).1c(\"1X\",$(8).S()),$(8).E(t)}).U(\"y\",3(){c t=$(8).D(\".9-q\").b(\"a.f\"),e=$(8).D(\".9-L\");w t.T(\"f\"),a.20(e.21().22-23),$(8).p(\"f\").D(\".9-L\").b(\".9-k\").E('<m H=\"I\" F=\"'+8.R+'\" K=\"1k...\"/>'),r.b(\".9-k\").p(\"G\").b(\"m.I\").1l(\"J\",0).O(3(){r.h({u:$(8).u()},i).b(\".9-k\").h({x:$(8).x()},i,3(){$(8).T(\"G\").b(\"m\").h({J:1},n)})}),!1})}),$(\".v\").U(\"y\",3(){w t(\"v\"),!1}),$(\".o\").U(\"y\",3(){w t(\"o\"),!1})}),3(){3 t(t,e,a){c n=t.24[0],i=25.26.27.28(n.1r,0);a=-(+a||-1),i=i.2a(3(t,n){w a*t.W[e].1t.1u().2e(n.W[e].1t.1u())});C(c s=0,l=i.j;l>s;++s)n.M(i[s])}3 e(e){c a,n=e.2f;2g(n&&(n=n.1r[0])&&(n=n.W),n)C(a=n.j;--a>=0;)(3(a){c i=1;n[a].2h=3(){C(c s=0,l=n.j;l>s;++s)n[s].P=n[s].P.2j(/(^| )1w|Y( |$)/g,\"$1$2\");w t(e,a,i=1-i),8.P+=1===i?\" 1w\":\" Y\",!1}})(a)}N.2m=e(z.2n(\"2o\"))}(),$(3(){$(\"#13-2p 1d\").2q({f:\"2r\",2s:\"2t\",2u:\"- \",2v:\"\"})});", 62, 156, "|||function|||||this|dte||find|var|script||active||animate||length|hl||img||next|addClass|gl||||width|prev|return|height|click|document|visibleItems|div|for|parents|html|src|loading|class|transparent|opacity|alt|sh|appendChild|window|load|className|changePoint|href|text|removeClass|on|link|cells|each|asc|javascript||entry|getElementsByTagName|nav|head|feeds|readLucky|style|Math|px|feed|posts|attr|ul|summary|max|results|li|createElement|showLucky|Loading|css|parent|json|trigger|in|callback|rows|fetchLuck|textContent|trim|type|desc|980|400|600|animationSpeed|1e3|autoPlay|wrap|autoPlaySpeed|3e3|pauseOnHover|enableResponsiveBreakpoints|responsiveBreakpoints|portrait|parseInt|first|480|landscape|640|prepend|tablet|768|alternate|openSearch|totalResults|rel|floor|title|random|feelingLucky|scrollTop|offset|top|40|tBodies|Array|prototype|slice|call|index|sort|mangakun|location|800|localeCompare|tHead|if|onmousedown|flexisel|replace|start|body|makeSortable|getElementById|mg_pglist|wrapper|tinyNav|selected|header|Navigation|indent|label" ["split"]("|"), 0, {}));
```

Any Help will be appriaciated. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Log it to your console and see what it returns. This is purposefully made non-readable and it's a pain to read.

If I were to guess I'd say your wordpress site got hacked and this is resulting in some ad redirects